# OLEDB connection

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

Im coonecting to access database using the below connection string :

```
      string strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Sally\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\StudentsApplication\\StudentsApplication\\School\\School.accdb";
```

but it's giving me an error Unrecognized database format. is the connection string wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this ,

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;Jet OLEDB:System Database=system.mdw;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably add "" around the path:

```
string strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\"C:\\Users\\Sally\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\StudentsApplication\\StudentsApplication\\School\\School.accdb\"";
```

Take a look a this site, it has examples for all kinds of databases connection strings:

[**Connection String Home Page**](http://www.carlprothman.net/Default.aspx?tabid=81)

Comment: That's because you need to use the right connection string for the type of database you're using. Because I don't know which one it is (you didn't say) I gave you a nice link with lots of connection strings. Find the database type there, and use that string. (You can't play with it much)

Answer (score 0):

The reason would be that the ACE provider for Microsoft Access is not installed.
Does your system has Office 2007? Its installed normally with Office 2007.
If no, please install and download [Office 2007 Data Connectivity Components](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23734)

Read this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/2a658b68-49c9-448e-8aca-778c1573ffaa/